# Opening a file handle with a specific block size

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to write some data to a tape drive - I am using a class found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15487/Magnetic-Tape-Data-Storage-Part-1-Tape-Drive-IO-Co

I can load the tape drive using the "Load" method fine, although when I attempt to write to the tape I get the following error:

> IO operation will not work. Most likely the file will become too long
>   or the handle was not opened to support synchronous IO operations.

I believe this problem is due to the file handle using an incorrect block size. I know the block size for the device is: 32768 - although how can I open a file handle using this block size?

```
TapeOperator TapeOperatorObject = new TapeOperator();

// Load tape 1
TapeOperatorObject.Load(@"\\.\Tape1");

// Write to tape drive
Console.WriteLine("Writing");
FileStream inputFile = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open);
TapeOperatorObject.Write(0, ReadFully(inputFile));

   public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The Write method in the class I am using is below:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Writes to the tape given stream starting from given postion
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startPos"></param>
        /// <param name="stream"></param>
        public void Write( long startPos, byte[] stream )
        {
            // Get number of blocks that will be nned to perform write
            uint numberOfBlocks = GetBlocksNumber( stream.Length );

            // Updates tape's current position
            SetTapePosition( startPos );

            byte[] arrayToWrite = new byte[ numberOfBlocks * BlockSize ];
            Array.Copy( stream, arrayToWrite, stream.Length );

            // Write data to the device
            m_stream.Write( stream, 0, stream.Length );
            m_stream.Flush();
        }
```

Thanks

- David